# How to populate datagridview from a particular row?

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview

Friends, I've a datagridview with 5 columns and 10 fixed rows. That means I've 5 columns with different fieldnames like(Id,FirstName,Middle Name,LastName,Age) and 10 rows with different field name like(City,State,Pin,Country,STDCode,PhoneNo,Mobile,Email,OtherContacts,Status). Now I want to populate this datagridviw with data from database using dataset/datatable. Can you suggest me, how will I start populating the grid say from position (1,0) or any other cell? Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can not use a `DataBinding` but need to insert data in the datagridview, row-by-row.

[this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview) has an example on both techniques.